# @wordpress/env cli doesn't seem to properly update permalink structure until visiting the WP Admin Permalink settings page

Tags: permalinks, wp-cli, wp-env

I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@wordpress/env to set up a local docker-based WordPress development environment, which has been working great so far. I'm trying to build a script using WordPress's CLI that sets the permalink structure to '/%postname%/', so that visiting `/sample-page` would work without any manual setup.

I've tried all of the following commands:

```
wp-env cli wp option set permalink_structure '/%postname%/'
wp-env cli wp rewrite structure '/%postname%/'
wp-env cli wp rewrite flush --hard
```

My problem is that even though the navigation bar shows a link to `http://localhost:8888/sample-page/`, actually trying to visit that page yields a "Not Found / The requested URL was not found on this server." page in response.

This situation only resolves itself the moment I visit the WP Admin Settings Permalink pages (no save changes click, and simple logging in doesn't fix it either), but I'd like to do this through the CLI, which I hope would be possible for automating site setup.

Any advice?